# postgresql: SQL Query to merge the contents from multiple rows using another column

Tags: postgresql, merge, multiple-columns

I have the table `history` with following columns:

```
row_id, msgid, sender, receiver, chatcontent, transdate, transtime
```

Each chat transcript is stored as a separate row in the table.

Scenario:
My framework splits the chat content in multiple transcripts if the content is more then 2048 characters, The data is stored in mulitple rows with same details such as msgid, sender, receiver, transdate and transtime only chatcontent is different with row_id as the sequence.

For example,
my contents in table are

```
001, msgid1, mark@test.int, james@test.int, this is a long tes, 2013-03-13, 13:55:34
002, msgid1, mark@test.int, james@test.int, t message which is, 2013-03-13, 13:55:34
003, msgid1, mark@test.int, james@test.int,  splitted in multi, 2013-03-13, 13:55:34
004, msgid1, mark@test.int, james@test.int, ple rows, 2013-03-13, 13:55:34
005, msgid2, james@test.int, mark@test.int, yup i got you, 2013-03-13, 13:56:12
```

Now I want to fetch the data in a single query which should have output as

```
msgid1, mark@test.int, james@test.int, this is a long test message which is splitted in multiple rows, 2013-03-13, 13:55:34
msgid2, james@test.int, mark@test.int, yup i got you, 2013-03-13, 13:56:12
```

How to do it. I am unable to fetch all the details in the single query. I am able to merge the chatcontent in one column using command but i dont want to hardcode the value of msgid

```
SELECT array_to_string(array(SELECT chatcontent FROM history where msgid='msgid1'),'');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT
    msgid,
    sender,
    receiver,
    transdate,
    transtime,
    array_to_string(array(
        select chatcontent
        from history
        where msgid = h.msgid
        order by row_id
        ), ' '
    ) chatcontent
from history h
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
order by 1
```